# Padding/gravity of buttons changing when styling android Alert dialog for dark mode?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to fix a bug in our React Native application where in dark mode, the native android Alert dialog is displaying a very dark gray background with black text on the buttons, making it unreadable:

[unreadable android Alert dialog in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79a7j.png)

The solution looks like applying a custom style to the Alert is the right way to go. I have my main styles in android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/splashscreen_bg</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

which produces the following result in light mode (unmodified):

[normal Android alert dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXESP.png)

To fix the dark mode issue, I've added another file in android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml with the following contents:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/splashscreen_bg</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
        </style>
        <style name="AlertTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
            <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
            <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
            <item name="android:colorAccent">#000000</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

Which seems to fix the color issue, producing the following result in dark mode:

[custom dark mode Android alert dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KvKB.png)

But now it looks like the padding or gravity on the buttons is messed up, like the space is below the buttons instead of above (like in the light mode screenshot).

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of?